# Powershell script to display all groups and their users

Tags: powershell, directory

I'm currently trying to write a script that displays each group and user in the domain.

```
        Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "**"} | select name -expandproperty name)

$Table = @()

$Record = [ordered]@{ "Group Name" = ""; "Name" = ""; "Username" = ""; }

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group | select name,samaccountname

foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) { 
$Record.Set_Item("Group Name", $Group) 
$Record.Set_Item("Name", $Member.name) 
$Record.Set_Item("Username", $Member.samaccountname) 
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord

}

}

$Table | export-csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It always returns these errors:

```
New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+='.
At C:\Users\tech\Desktop\list.ps1:17 char:14
+ $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+='.
At C:\Users\tech\Desktop\list.ps1:17 char:14
+ $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Repeating over and over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

BTW This is server 2012 R2

Comment: Please look at basic syntax for defining hashtables / dictionaries in PowerShell on internet for these basic errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-AdGroup -filter * |
    ForEach-Object{
        $groupname=$_.Name
        Get-ADGroupMember $_ |
            ForEach-Object{
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    GroupName=$groupname
                    Name=$_.name
                    SamAccountNamename=$_.samaccountname
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain your answer?

Comment: It's a powershell script, save it in a .ps1 file

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize $objRecord as an Array:

```
$objRecord = @()
```

Then you can += it.

Also, you should just do:

```
$objRecord += New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table
```

instead of:

```
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record $Table += $objrecord
```

I.e.: you're doing 2 assignments. You either do a=a+1 or a+=1.

I'd go with Steve's answer, though.

Comment: Oh, BTW, it seems your $objRecord should be $Table instead.